# How to solve $\lim_{x \to \ 0^+} (\mid \ln(x) \mid)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to solve $$\lim_{x \to \ 0^+} (\mid \ln(x) \mid)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\left(|\ln(x)| \right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\ln(|\ln(x)|) \right)$$
One can compute this limit as a composition of well known limits.

Answer (score -1):

$\forall x$ such as $ 0<x<\dfrac{1}{e²}$, $(\mid \ln(x) \mid)^{1/x}>2^{1/x}$

And $\lim_{x \to \ 0^+} 2^{1/x}=+\infty$ ...

Comment: Those fractions in the superscript are completely unreadable, it's better to use $2^{1/x}$.

Comment: Sorry my error in numerics, I get infinity.